# How to replace string with register content?

Tags: replace, register

For example, substitute `:` with register 0's content.
What's the correct command for `:s/:/"0/`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*N.B. In all the below, I presume that your question is only about the method of accessing the register's contents from an ex command, and that the rest of your `:substitute` command (which replaces only the first match on the current line) does what you require. If you actually want to replace globally, you will need to use a `%` range and the `g` flag: `:%s/find/replace/g`*

### Interactively in Command Line Mode

If this is being done interactively, you can do so by inserting the contents of the register into the command using <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>:

Type the first part of your command, `:s/:/`

Then type <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to insert the contents of the yank register `"0` into the command line.

Note that you may need to then edit the command line slightly before pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> to run the substitution. e.g. if the register contained a string that included a forward slash `/`.

### In Vimscript

If this is in a script, then you can use the `@0` notation or the `getreg()` function to access register contents. You can also then perform escaping automatically.

e.g.

```
execute 's/:/' . escape(getreg('0'), '/')
```

### Update: In a Macro

If you want to do this in a macro recorded from keystrokes, the first method works fine: <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> is recorded just like other keystrokes.

If you're instead creating a macro by assigning a string value to a register, you can use something like the below:

```
:let @q = ":s/:/\<C-R>0\<CR>"
```

I'm using the `:let` command above for simplicity, but the `setreg()` function is more robust.

### Further Reading

- `:help c_CTRL-R`
- `:help expr9`
- `:help getreg()`
- `:help :execute`
- `:help string`

Comment: I wish to use it in a macro. Could you point me the command.

Comment: @Fisher See my update

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for this same thing today, and thanks to Rich's answer regarding usage of execute in Vimscript, came to this interactive method that does not involve Ctrl-R.

```
:s/:/\=getreg('0')/g
```

Thank you @Rich.

Answer (score 3):

Besides @Rich's solution of using a substitution, `:s`, uou can use the `c`, `gn`, and `<c-r>` to do this as well.

```
cgn<c-r>0<esc>
```

Now you can simply spam repeat, `.` to do the next substitution.

However if spamming the dot command is not desirable, then you can make a macro to do it for you.

```
:let @q = '.@q'
```

Now you can simply run the macro from the `"q` register via `@q` which will repeat the `.` command until it runs out of matches.

Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/).